# K8s Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "nginx" not found

Tags: kubernetes

## Problem

[Coursera Google Cloud Fundamentals: Getting Started with Kubernetes Engine](https://www.coursera.org/learn/gcp-fundamentals/lecture/umRjO/demo-getting-started-with-kubernetes-engine)
has the  instructions  to run and expose the pod. The demo video shows it is working.

[image]
However, it causes the error in my execution. How to fix?

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx:1.10.0
kubectl expose deployment nginx --type LoadBalancer --port 80 
---
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "nginx" not found
```

### Environment

GCP k8s.

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.1", GitCommit:"632ed300f2c34f6d6d15ca4cef3d3c7073412212", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-19T15:45:37Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20+", GitVersion:"v1.20.8-gke.2100", GitCommit:"4cd085fda961821985d176d25b67445c1efb6ba1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-07-16T09:22:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.13b5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
WARNING: version difference between client (1.22) and server (1.20) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1
```

Comment: Based on `nginx image version`, it's **a little bit** outdated tutorial.

Answer (score 9):

## Cause

`kubectl run` does not create `deployment`.

['Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions "nginx" not found' when exposing NodePort #31](https://github.com/ivanfioravanti/kubernetes-the-hard-way-on-azure/issues/31)

> Did you create a pod with "kubectl run"? If yes, that doesn't create a deployment with (at least) kubectl v1.18.2, so instead use "kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx:1.10.0"

## Fix

Create a deployment as in [Creating and exploring an nginx deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-stateless-application-deployment/#creating-and-exploring-an-nginx-deployment) from a YAML or run `kubectl create deployment ...`.

```
$ kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx:1.12.0
deployment.apps/nginx created

$ kubectl expose deployment nginx --type LoadBalancer --port 80
service/nginx exposed

$ kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.83.240.1    <none>           443/TCP        44m
nginx        LoadBalancer   10.83.246.84   35.225.127.227   80:30825/TCP   60s
```